# Powershell - exclude last record from array from getting join

Tags: powershell

i was wondering if anyone could help me with my issue. i have this code:

```
$test = ForEach ($file from $folder){
        join-path -path $path -childpath $file
{
$test -join ","
```

if i have for example 12 records on the array, i need the first 11 to have "," 
path\file1.txt,
path\file2.txt,
...
path\file11.txt,
path\file12.txt (should be the result) but what i'm getting is path\file12.txt,

how can i have the last record not contain ","?

any help is much appreciated.

thank you

Comment: Did you try the code? Do you really get a comma in the end? How do you fill in your variable `$folder`? ... what you descibe should not happen ...

Comment: If `path\file12.txt` is truly the only thing in `$test[-1]`, then this would not happen.

Comment: the output gives me 
path\text1.txt,
path\text2.txt,
...
path\text11.txt,
path\text12.txt,

Comment: @adminofthings so on the $test[-1] -join "," ?

Comment: Try to run this code: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7 -join ' + '`  is there a ` + ` in the end then?

Comment: No. What is just the output of `$test[-1]`

Comment: As a workaround, you can do `$test = $test -replace ',[^,]*$'`. But I would advise finding the root cause. Using `-join` on an array actually joins all elements together as a single string with the delimiter provided. It won't append the delimiter to the end of the string. You likely have a blank space or invisible character as the last element of your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you can do the following:

```
$test = $test -replace ',[^,]*$'
```

---

However, I would investigate the root cause of the issue as there could be a number of issues (or nonissues) with your data. See below for how this could happen if your final `$folder` element contains an ending comma:

```
# Example 1
# The $folder final element contains a comma in its string
# The -join does not add the comma because it is part of the string already
$folder = 'one','two','three','four,'
$path = 'c:\temp'
$test = foreach ($file in $folder) {
    Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath $file
}
$test -join ','

#output
c:\temp\one,c:\temp\two,c:\temp\three,c:\temp\four,
```

In the example above, we should be able to look at the last element (`[-1]`) of `$test` and find the trailing comma:

```
$test[-1]
#output
c:\temp\four,
```

---

See below if `$test` is manipulated to have a blank (or `$null`) element added to the end of it:

```
# Example 2
# $test gets a space added as the final element
$folder = 'one','two','three','four'
$path = 'c:\temp'
$test = foreach ($file in $folder) {
    Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath $file
}
$test += ' '
$test -join ','

#output
c:\temp\one,c:\temp\two,c:\temp\three,c:\temp\four,
```

The last element of `$test` here will be a blank line:

```
PS > $test[-1]

PS >
```

---

**Edit Based on Comments:**

You can use the format operator `-f` to format each query string. Then use the `-join` operator to combine all your string elements together.

```
$query = ForEach ($file in $test) {
    $sqlquery = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath $file
    "file='{0}'" -f $sqlquery
}
$query -join ",`n"
```

Comment: $path = 'c:\folder'
cd $path
#dir

$test = Get-ChildItem -path $path  -Exclude lite* -Recurse -File -Name

#write-host $test

$query = ForEach ($file in $test) {
    
   $sqlquery = join-path -path $path -ChildPath $file
   "file='"+$sqlquery+"',`n"     
}

#output $query content
write-output $query
output is below:
file='C:\Folder\202007104.txt',
file='C:\Folder\202007104.txt',
file='C:\Folder\202007105.txt',
file='C:\Folder\202007106.txt',
....
file="C:\Folder\202007112.txt',

hope it makes sense?

Comment: You are not using `-join` there at all. Let `-join` do the work. If you want newline characters, then use ```$pathArray -join ",`n"```.

Comment: @Ralph, I added an edit at the end of my post that should help.